# Covariant Types

Tags: rust, type-theory

According the Rustonomicon, `&mut T` is invariant over `T`. How can the following code compile when `&mut (str, str)` is not a subtype of `&mut (T, T)`?

```rust
fn swap<T: Copy>(pair: &mut (T, T)) {
    let temp = pair.0;
    pair.0 = pair.1;
    pair.1 = temp;
}

fn main() {
    let mut pair = ("left", "right");
    swap(&mut pair);
    println!("{:?}", pair);
}
```

The relevant chapter is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/subtyping.html)

The Rustonomicon implies that you can call `f: (T) -> U` on `f(V)` only if `V` is a subtype of `T`. (4th code block, the example is `evil_feeder(pet: &mut Animal)` being called with `&mut Cat`). How can the above example compile if it's not a subtype?

Comment: This feels like a misunderstanding of how generics work; there is no `T`. You're calling `swap::<&str>()` so there is no conversion or sub-typing to consider here.

Comment: Rust-omicron, mut, invariant... lexical field of the covid xd

Comment: In the rare occasions when Rust speaks of subtypes and variance, that applies only to *lifetimes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can compile because you are not using a `&mut (str, str)`. What you have is an `&mut (&'static str, &'static str)`. This is because string literals are references to the read-only memory where the actual string was stored in the executable.

It can fulfill the requirement of the function because even though `str` does not implement `Copy`, all immutable references implement `Copy`.

Comment: What rules is the compiler applying? The Rustonomicon implies that you can call `f : (T) -> U` on `f(V)` only if `V` is a subtype of `T`. (4th code block, the example is `evil_feeder(pet: &mut Animal)` being called with `&mut Cat`). How can the example in the question be called if it's not a subtype?

Comment: I hope I'm not mixing up the wording, but it does not imply `V` is a subtype of `T`. Rust does not really have the concept of subtypes. Instead you can think of it as saying that there exists a function `g : (K) -> V` with concrete types `K` and `V` that can be derived from any function `f : (T) -> U` where `K ϵ T, V ϵ U`. In your case, `T = {x | x impl Copy}, U = {()}`. Actually, I think if we are going for mathematical correctness `f` should probably be a tuple of `f = <T, U, O>` where `O` is the code since `f : x -> y` implies `f` is a function which isn't quite how I described it.

Answer (score 3):

Variance is primarily about type coercion and only secondarily about generics.

See also https://ehsanmkermani.com/2019/03/16/variance-in-rust-an-intuitive-explanation/, https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html, and https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types.

Comment: This is the ANSWER.